# Does anyone have or know of any example of a custom popup editor for Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We are seeking a working example of a popup editor (ideally textarea) using Tabulator. Does anyone have or know of one of a working example?

The Tabulator folks say this is up to the dev https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2048. And while we can see not providing this as part of Tabulator proper, an example showing how to glue it together would be nice because it is Tabulator the integration is with.

And yes, we are aware there are other grids that have this already, but they have not met our needs in other areas that Tabulator has, so we'd really like to tackle this with Tabulator.

Here is a rough start using a JQuery UI dialog, but we cannot figure out how to get he cell value to update and close the dialog https://jsfiddle.net/1kmrLoj8/16/

```js
function onChange(e){
  if(((cell.getValue() === null || typeof cell.getValue() === "undefined") && editor.value !== "") || editor.value !== cell.getValue()){
    if(success(editor.value)){  
      cell.setValue(editor.value); //persist value if successfully validated incase editor is used as header filter
      $(dialog).dialog('close'); //does not work        
    }
  }else{
    cancel();     
    $(dialog).dialog('close'); //does not work
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tabulator is only built to display tables, it does not create an elements outside of the table itself.

If you want to use modals or popups then i would suggest choosing a 3rd party modal library that works for your needs and trigger it from an event in Tabulator.

If you want it to act as an editor then i would suggest triggering the modal on the ***cellClick*** or ***RowClick*** events.

These events get pass in a [Component Object](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components) representing the cell or row that has been clicked. you can then call functions on these objects to change any updated data in the table