# Custom Cell Formatter to Hide/Show Truncated Text

Tags: tabulator

One of the columns in my table can contain a large amount of text, several paragraphs.  This causes each row to be very tall and the table not readable.

I would like to set up a custom formatter for this column to automatically truncate the viewable text after X characters (X would be configurable) and include ellipses after that point and then display a "Show More" link.  Clicking on "Show More" would then reveal all of the text in the cell, causing the row's height to expand to show all of the text, then toggling the "Show More" link to say "Show Less".  Clicking on "Show Less" would return to the truncated view of the cell.

I can get part of this to work by simply returning from the custom formatter the first X characters of the text followed by a an element with display set to null containing the rest of the text. Clicking on "Show More" would change the element's display to inline.

In one sense this works, because the hidden text is displayed in part when Show More is clicked, but only the part that will fit into the existing cell's size.  The rest is hidden and an ellipses is added.

For example, the initial load would show:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy

> ...Show More

Then after toggling it would show:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog... [this ellipses is added automatically by the CSS]

> Show Less

How do I get the cell to expand to show all of the text?

A trickier version of this is to support HTML content, which can't be truncated as easily and still support showing the formatting properly.  text-overflow:ellipses seems like it might solve that problem, but I have not figured out how to get it to work in this context.  Indeed, text-overflow:ellipses might overall be a simpler solution to this problem if it can be made to work.

Btw, the alternative is to show the full text in a modal dialog, although I have not investigated that approach yet.  (I don't think Tabulator supports a modal dialog out of the box, so I would need to add one, such as jquery's.  See:  [Does anyone have or know of any example of a custom popup editor for Tabulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086326/does-anyone-have-or-know-of-any-example-of-a-custom-popup-editor-for-tabulator))